# Extracting dictionary nested elements into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of dictionaries **l1**, that looks like this:

```
[{'A1': 'string',
  'B1': {'ba': 'string',
        'bb': 'string',
        'bc': 'string',
        'bd': 'string',
        'be': 'string'},
  'C1': {'ca': 'string',
        'cb': [[[123,123],[123,123]]]},
  'D1': 'string'},
  ...]
```

Some of the dictionaries (l1 elements) might have some of the keys missing, for example, the second list element of l1 might not have *'bc':''string'* key/value pair.

I need to extract the following top and nested key/value elements into a dataframe, which will look like this:

```
bc      bd      cb                        D1
string  string  [[[123,123],[123,123]]]   string
N/A     string  [[[123,123],[123,123]]]   string
...
string  N/A     [[[123,123],[123,123]]]   string
```

The code I have is below:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['bc','bd','cb','D1']

for i in l1:
    temp_df = temp_df.append({'bc': i.get(['B1']['bc'],'N/A'),
                              'bd': i.get(['B1']['bd'],'N/A'),
                              'cb': i.get(['C1']['cb'],'N/A'),
                              'D1': i.get(['D1'],'N/A')}, 
                               ignore_index=True)
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-113-543c6addad42> in <module>
       1 for i in l1:
 ----> 2     temp_df = temp_df.append({'bc': i.get(['B1']['bc'],'N/A'),
       3                                 'bd': i.get(['B1']['bd'],'N/A'),
       4                                 'C1': i.get(['C1']['cb'],'N/A'),
       5                                 'D1': i.get(['D1'],'N/A')}, 

  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `i.get(['B1']['bc'],'N/A')`, which is not valid python syntax, using `i.get('B1', {}).get('bc', 'N/A')` to get nested keys.  Also don't dynamically append to pandas dataframe, it's slow. Append to list first and then convert the list to dataframe.

```
lst = []
for i in l1:
    lst.append({
        'bc': i.get('B1', {}).get('bc', 'N/A'),
        'bd': i.get('B1', {}).get('bd', 'N/A'),
        'cb': i.get('C1', {}).get('cb', 'N/A'),
        'D1': i.get('D1', 'N/A')
    })

pd.DataFrame(lst)

       bc      bd                          cb      D1
0  string  string  [[[123, 123], [123, 123]]]  string
```

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to @Psidom's answer for your error, however, to achieve what you are trying to do, you can alternatively use `json_normalize`.

```
pd.json_normalize(l1).rename(columns={
    'B1.bc': 'bc',
    'B1.bd': 'bd',
    'C1.cb': 'cb'
}).fillna('N/A')[['bc', 'bd', 'cb', 'D1']]
```